# Using a prompt() variable in a function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

In this code:

```
var ask = prompt("Enter contact's first name");

function Contact(firstName, surname, age) {
    this.Name = firstName;
    this.Surname = surname;
    this.Age = age;
}

var contact = function (person) {
    for (var prop in person) {
        document.write(prop + ": " + person[prop] + "</br>");
    }
};

var Alice = new Contact("Alice", "Example", 24);
var Bob = new Contact("Bob", "Bobby", 39);


contact(ask);
```

Why will it now work with the prompt box as the variable? It works fine when you just use a string in the contact function. Is it something to with because it is a variable not a string?

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is iterating on the array of characters in the string. So it is actually working. Not sure what your goal is though.

The variables Alice and Bob are not used anywhere. That would make me think that you would like to be able to fetch some contacts data depending on the input. Modifying your contact function as follows (using eval) you will be able to match the input of the prompt with possible exising contacts variables:

```
var contact = function (personName) {
    var personObject = eval(personName)
    for (var prop in personObject) {
        document.write(prop + ": " + personObject[prop] + "</br>");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your `contact()` function with a string, and then trying to do a `for...in` loop on it, which makes no sense.  Sure, you can use `for...in` with a string, but why would you want to?  It just loops through each character.

Comment: Fair point, it is really just a project so I can practise using for in structures and objects

Answer (score -1):

i plugged this code into a compiler and it did not work because you are not using if statements to denote a function